# Wordpress Roots Bedrock Composer Update

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

Does anyone know if Wordpress Roots Bedrock Composer updates the Wordpress version? I have tried `composer update` but it doesn't update the Wordpress version. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Danish.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress is treated as a required dependency by composer, so yes. It is updated when you run `composer update`.

You can check if your composer packages are outdated with: `composer outdated` (or `composer show -l`). Each package will be listed showing the desired version (the version number specified in `composer.json`) and the current released version.

Running `composer update`, (or `composer.phar update`) will update each package to your specified version. If you want to update the package to the latest version, but you're unaware of the current version number. You can remove the package, and then add it back in. Composer will add the package to your required dependency list with the latest version.

Comment: should be the accepted answer, I am ale to update the version in composer.json, next time `composer update` runs (i rebuild the container) it updated bedrock version

Comment: Use the option `--with-all-dependencies` (or `-W`):
`composer require roots/wordpress:6.4.3 -W`
This solves the error: `...the package is fixed to ...(lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match.`
See [Updating WordPress and WordPress plugin versions with Composer](https://roots.io/bedrock/docs/composer/)